# Invalid Parameters Passed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Still on my GAN code for network traffic generation. My code is giving me the error that the parameters i passed for the train_test_split function is invalid. What do I do? Please see the code and error message below;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-a2836ba27bc4> in <module>
      9     cross_validation_flg = False
     10     benign_file = '../data/attack_normal_data/benign_data.csv'
---> 11     benign_model, benign_test_loader = run_main(benign_file, num_features=41)
     12     # Save the model checkpoint
     13     torch.save(benign_model.state_dict(), 'benign_model_epoches%d.ckpt' % num_epochs)

<ipython-input-44-0a86075f4966> in run_main(input_file, num_features)
      6 
      7     # X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(value_x, value_y, train_size=0.7, 
shuffle=True)
----> 8     train_sampler, test_sampler = train_test_split(dataset, split_percent=0.7, shuffle=True)
      9     cntr = Counter(dataset.y)
     10     print('dataset: ', len(dataset), ' y:', sorted(cntr.items()))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, 
**options)
   2123 
   2124     if options:
-> 2125         raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))
   2126 
   2127     arrays = indexable(*arrays)

TypeError: Invalid parameters passed: {'split_percent': 0.7}
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Please be concise to your question . Post you code from where the problem started and what output you want to get from that

Answer (score -1):

I used train_size = 0.7 instead, and it worked.